# how do I load admin-styles.css after load-styles.php in Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

I am loading admin-styles with

```
function load_admin_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/admin-style.css' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_scripts' );
```

I would like to load this after the styles in load-styles.php, how do I do this? I've tried adding 999 to the action so I assume I need a later hook.